# AS3 - graphics.clear()

Tags: actionscript-3

I call the function below from the context menu and graphics get cleared. If the call comes from within another function it don't. 
Why it's not working than?

```
          function removeFrame(e:Event=null):void{
            holder.graphics.clear();
            }

        function cleanIt(e:Event=null):void{ 
        removeFrame() 
    } 
    // NOT working by calling it like this:
        cleanIt() 

// It's Working if I call the function directly from the right-click menu:
 menuitem1.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,cleanIt);
```

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you show more code, how is the function called? It looks like it's an event listener function, which can change the scope of what `this` means (ie. `this.holder`). You could make the function class level: `function removeFrame(e:Event=null):void{` and have it inside the class. Though it's hard to tell exactly without seeing more code.

I've tried in an fla file

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.ui.ContextMenu;
import flash.ui.ContextMenuItem;

var holder:Sprite = new Sprite();
holder.graphics.beginFill(0x443311,1);
holder.graphics.drawCircle(10,10,300);
addChild(holder);   
var cm:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
var menuitem1:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("HAHA")
cm.customItems.push(menuitem1);
contextMenu = cm;

function removeFrame(e:Event=null):void{
    holder.graphics.clear();
}

function cleanIt(e:Event=null):void{ 
    removeFrame() 
}

cleanIt();
menuitem1.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,cleanIt);
```

and `cleanIt` works for both, need more info or code to know what's going on.

Comment: I call the above function from this function at it's not working: `function cleanIt(e:Event=null):void{
removeFrame()
} cleanIt()` But it is working if I call the function directly from the right-click menu: `menuitem1.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,cleanIt);
` Where is the difference? Thanks.

Comment: can you update the code in the question to show how you are calling it?

Comment: using your code worked for me, updated answer with the code I used